# Unterschied zwischen einem konkreten und abstrakten Merkmal

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Bei der Interview-Technik 'Laddering' wird bei der Erhebung von Merkmalen, die befragte Probanden in ihren Antworten nennen, zwischen

> **konkreten Merkmalen**

und

> **abstrakten Merkmalen**

unterschieden. Mir ist jedoch aktuell nicht wirklich klar, worin sich ein konkretes und ein abstraktes Merkmal unterscheiden - bzw. wie man die erhobenen Merkmale beiden Kategorien richtig zuordnet.

Einen Leitfaden hierzu konnte ich leider nirgends finden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ein Konkretum bezeichnet

> etwas Gegenständliches, also etwas sinnlich Erfahrbares

Ein Abstraktum hingegen bezeichnet

> etwas Nichtgegenständliches

Im Kontext der genannten Interviewmethode aus der Marktforschung wäre ein konkretes Merkmal also zum Beispiel Farbe, Größe oder Geruch eines Produkts. Ein abstraktes Merkmal hingegen wäre zum Beispiel das Ansehen eines Produkts (im Sinne eines Prestigeprodukts) oder Eigenschaften, die dem Produkt (subjektiv) zugesprochen werden, aber nicht objektiv messbar sind.

Comment: Danke schön. Auf den Punkt getroffen :)

Comment: Kälte ist ein Abstraktum. Gleichwohl ist Kälte etwas sinnlich Erfahrbares. Oder die Röte.

Answer (score 1):

Lt. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laddering) geht es beim Laddering darum, von abstrakten Produkteigenschaften zum konkreten Nutzen für den Befragten zu gelangen.

Eine abstrakte Eigenschaft von Gauloises-Tabak war es, besonders stark zu sein. Der konkrete Vorteil für mich war, selten angeschnorrt zu werden.

Mein Laptop hat einen Digitalstift. Mein konkreter Nutzen ist, damit Skizzen anfertigen zu können. Handschrifteingabe dagegen interessiert mich nicht - die kann das Gerät aber auch.

Comment: Gute Beispiele. Danke! :)